# Getting an imported object's name

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to create a list from a directory and import each item with a `for` loop:

```
file_list = sorted(os.listdir(path_to_3ds))
autodesk_list = [item for item in file_list if item.endswith('.fbx')]

for item in autodesk_list:
    path_to_files = os.path.join(path_to_3ds, item)
    bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath = path_to_files)
```

How can I get the object name of the imported item and export it as `object name + ' export'`?

Answer (score 8):

You can use Python set operations.

- Make a set from all objects in the scene before the import
- Perform the import
- Make another set from all objects and subtract the set you made earlier

The only objects left in the set are the ones that were imported.

```
old_objs = set(context.scene.objects)
bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath="/home/simon/untitled.fbx")
imported_objs = set(context.scene.objects) - old_objs

print("Imported:", imported_objs)
```

[image]

Comment: @batFINGER agreed, I changed it.

Answer (score 2):

When calling any import operator (fbx, obj or something), all imported objects are going to be selected (as you may already noticed). To get that selection, you can use  [bpy.context.selected_objects](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.context.html?highlight=selected_objects#bpy.context.selected_objects):

```
>>> bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath="/path/to/file/scene-01.fbx")
>>> [o.name for o in bpy.context.selected_objects]
['imported_obj.001', 'imported_obj.002', 'imported_obj.003' ...]
...
```

Another way would be an iteration through all objects to check their actual *select state*: `imported_objects = [o for o in bpy.context.scene.objects if o.select]`.

---

In case of importing multiple files, you can just add all the new names to a list (initialized before the loop) since all object names in blender are *unique* by design:

```
import bpy

files = (
    "/path/to/file/scene-01.fbx", 
    "/path/to/file/scene-02.fbx",
    "/path/to/file/scene-03.fbx"
    )

imported_objects = []
for f in files:
    bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath=f)

    # Object names
    imported_objects += [o.name for o in bpy.context.selected_objects]

    # Object data
    #imported_objects += bpy.context.selected_objects[:]

print (imported_objects)
```