# Get list of objects from an instanced group that was made real

Tags: python, scripting, groups

I am making a script that makes a Group Instance of an existing group of objects, makes it real, and then adds the objects to a new group. Making the instance, making it real, and adding a selection of objects to a group are easy. The problem is figuring out what objects just came out of the Group Instance once it was made real.

I have a version working where it gets a list of each object in the original group, and then after the instanced group is made real, looks for that list but with .001 added to the name. This works as long as the original group does not have any objects that end in .001 already (as those would change to .002), and as long as there isn't some other object with the same name but ending in .001 already (in which case the wrong object gets added to the list.)

But since I can't necessarily control for the names, I want to change it to use some other method to figure out which objects just came out of the group instance. I can do it based on layer, but that can also lead to problems. So I am looking for a way to know what objects are inside a Group Instance, or how to identify objects that just came out of one when it was made real. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/108112/29401

Comment: Yes, that does it!